# If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $K$ is a subgroup of $H$, then $$|G:K|=|G:H||H:K|$$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I would like to prove that : If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $K$ is a subgroup of $H$, then

$$|G:K|=|G:H||H:K|$$

I appreciate any clear explanation of this. Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an intuitive explanation:

$G$ is decomposed into $[G:H]$ "copies" of $H$ and each of those is decomposed into $[H:K]$ copies of $K$. Hence, $G$ is decomposed into $[G:H][H:K]$ "copies" of $K$.